# Is salt master and minion version upgrade doable via bootstrap-salt.sh?

Tags: salt-stack

I have servers that are using salt. Salt master and minions have been installed via `bootstrap-salt.sh` (https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/salt_bootstrap.html).

Is the upgrade also doable via `bootstrap-salt.sh vZZZ` - just  bypassing newer version? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see in sources - yes, `bootstrap-salt.sh` will upgrade your master and minion (keep in mind command-line keys to make sure you're installing what you want!) if older version is installed.

Comment: Thanks! Also my test shows that version can bumped up and down using `bootstrap-salt.sh`.